# Frame dragging affecting bending of light

Tags: visible-light, frame-dragging

If the frame dragging causes precession of an orbit does it mean that due to the rotating character of space the amount of bending of light will be added to the angular displacements of spacetime points that transfer the light beam so the bending should be greather in the direction of frame dragging?And also do we have less time lagging for a distant observer because the light spends less time to travel through a space that moves in direction of light propagation?

Comment: *If the frame dragging causes precession of an orbit* You can have orbital precession in GR without any frame dragging.

Comment: @G.Smith What is the cause of the orbital precession with no presence of frame dragging?

Comment: GR leads to a $1/r^3$ term in the radial effective potential. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Relation_to_Newtonian_physics).